# useEffect not working when I update the state from another component

Tags: reactjs

I have a state in main component its name filter and setFilter , the setFilter is sent to sidebar component as porps to filter the posts based on category , the problem is when the state changed in sidebar , the use effect not fire

```
**main.js**    
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({});
const [cases, setCases] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("============ FROM USE Effect=============", filter)
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post/' + new URLSearchParams(filter))
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw Error('could not fetch the data for that resource');
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
            setCases(data)
            setIsPending(false)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
}, [filter]);



**sidebar.js**


const changeFilter = (e, categoryName) => {
    const value = e.target.checked
    handleFilter((filter) => {
        console.log(filter , "From sidebarrrrrrrrr")
        filter[categoryName] = value;
        return filter
    })
} 

<FormControlLabel control={<CustomizedCheckbox />} onChange={(e) => changeFilter(e, cate.category) } label={<Box className={classes.label} >{cate.category}</Box>} />
```

Comment: Your examples formatting is a bit though to read, but it looks like you are directly setting state (using `=`) rather than using the `setFilter()` function, which is not recommended and will not trigger effects.

Comment: We need more code and looks like you're mutating the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a new state on `handleFilter`:

```
handleFilter((filter) => ({...filter, [categoryName]: value}))
```

Answer (score 1):

To update state you must use build-in function which is returned as second element of an array from useState hook.

```
[state, setState] = useState(initialValue)
// state - state itself
// setState - a function you must use to change state and fire up all re-render and related events
```

So the proper way to set state in your case is:

```
const changeFilter = (e, categoryName) => {
  const value = e.target.checked
  setFilter({...filter, [categoryName]: value})
}
```